# Suppress a recipient in DocuSign

Tags: docusignapi

We have enabled document level visibility and have few roles, client, manager etc,.with routing enabled and everything works great. We now want to add a new role for "witness" (or whatever that role might be). However, this role does not have to receive any documents post docusign, once signatures are complete. How do I suppress a role from not receiving any completed documents from the final "signature complete" envelope?

Answer (score 0):

So, one way to do that is to remove the default option that sends all signers the completed document. To do that you have to log in as an administrator and go to the "Setting" app and then select **Email Preferences** and uncheck "An envelope is completed".

Now, that will impact all your recipients, and I suspect you do want some of them to receive the final document, which means you may want to provide it to them in another manner. You can add them as Carbon Copy (CC) recipients or you can send them the final document from your connect webhook separately.

[image]